# external monitor won't go full screen with MBP 13" 2020

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, catalina, resolution

I searched but couldn't find anything relevant.

I have a 2020 Macbook pro 13" that's updated to the latest OS. I got a secondary external monitor AOC 24B1H 24" LCD Monitor (1920x1080 @60Hz). I connected it thru a vava usb-c Hub and found that the image on the external monitor would only expand to about 90% of the screen, leaving a black boarder that's not being used (but can be used). I tried connecting it thru a different Anker usb-c hub and still got the same issue, that the screen is only 90% full with there being a black boarder that's not supposed to be there. I even used a friend's monitor with both hubs and found that the same issue came up with that monitor as well. Both monitors work well with other laptops and connections, showing the image at full screen using 100%.

I'm thinking it's an issue with the 2020 MBP 13" but can't seem to resolve the issue. I even tried to use switch res x and didn't manage to resolve the issue. Does anybody have any ideas?

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C73aK.jpg)

Comment: This is likely a setting on the monitor. Do you have the manual that references the settings? I found it here https://aoc-pim.s3.amazonaws.com/USA%20content/B1/24B1H_English.pdf. There is at least one setting (Image Ratio) which might help here. There may also be settings for overscan or the ability to "stretch" the image to fill the monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the resource! Unfortunately the "image ratio" setting has been disabled in the monitor OSD. I tried a 2019 mbp 13" and it works fine with this monitor, being full screen. It's just my 2020 macbook mbp 13 that seems to have issues, not being full screen.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I fixed the issue! I had to reboot the computer in safe mode and it fixed the image issues.